# PHP - Combinación de Array

Tags: php, array

Tengo el siguiente array:

```
Array
(
    [ID] => 2
    [TokenPersona] => 54N65J4K7B6H9B76N9L67KJ54J5VN3B
    [Contenido] => POP DAT!
    [Date] => 2016-11-27 11:57:11
    [tipoPrivacidad] => 1
    [ControlEdad] => 0
)
```

Y tengo el array que deseo agregar:

```
Array
(
    [ID] => 3
    [TokenPersona] => 54N65J4K7B6H9B76N9L67KJ54J5VN3B
    [Contenido] => Hey dot :v
    [Date] => 2016-11-27 12:13:15
    [tipoPrivacidad] => 1
    [ControlEdad] => 0
)
```

Para ello uso:

```
$var = array_merge($array1,$array2);
```

Pero su resultado es:

```
Array
(
    [ID] => 3
    [TokenPersona] => 54N65J4K7B6H9B76N9L67KJ54J5VN3B
    [Contenido] => Hey dot :v
    [Date] => 2016-11-27 12:13:15
    [tipoPrivacidad] => 1
    [ControlEdad] => 0
)
```

Y yo quisiera el siguiente resultado:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [ID] => 2
            [TokenPersona] => 54N65J4K7B6H9B76N9L67KJ54J5VN3B
            [Contenido] => POP DAT!
            [Date] => 2016-11-27 11:57:11
            [tipoPrivacidad] => 1
            [ControlEdad] => 0
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [ID] => 3
            [TokenPersona] => 54N65J4K7B6H9B76N9L67KJ54J5VN3B
            [Contenido] => Hey dot :v
            [Date] => 2016-11-27 12:13:15
            [tipoPrivacidad] => 1
            [ControlEdad] => 0
        )
)
```

¿En qué estoy fallando?

### En respuesta al comentario realizado por Error404

No uso **array_merge_recursive** debido a que me daría como respuesta lo siguiente:

```
Array
(
    [ID] => Array
        (
            [0] => 2
            [1] => 3
        )
    [TokenPersona] => Array
        (
            [0] => 54N65J4K7B6H9B76N9L67KJ54J5VN3B
            [1] => 54N65J4K7B6H9B76N9L67KJ54J5VN3B
        )
    [Contenido] => Array
        (
            [0] => POP DAT!
            [1] => Hey dot :v
        )

    [Date] => Array
        (
            [0] => 2016-11-27 11:57:11
            [1] => 2016-11-27 12:13:15
        )
    [tipoPrivacidad] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
            [1] => 1
        )

    [ControlEdad] => Array
        (
            [0] => 0
            [1] => 0
        )
)
```

Y **no es así** como quiero el resultado.

Comment: ¿Has probado a usar `array_merge_recursive`?

Comment: El problema de usar **recursive** es que me separa todos los indices.

Comment: Te los agrupa por índices.

Comment: Dale un vistazo a mi editado :)

Comment: Pensándolo mejor creo que mi respuesta es lo que buscas. Puedes asignar un array directamente a otro en PHP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lo que puedes realizar es agregar directamente cada uno de los arrays a un tercer array. Por ejemplo, tomando como referencia estos dos array:

```
$array1 = Array("ID" => 2, "TokenPersona" => "54N65J4K7B6H9B76N9L67KJ54J5VN3B", "Contenido" => "POP DAT!");
$array2 = Array("ID" => 5, "TokenPersona" => "54N65J4", "Contenido" => "DAT POP!");
```

Puedes asignar cada uno de los arrays a un tercer array de la siguiente manera:

```
$array3[] = $array1;
$array3[] = $array2;
```

Por tanto, al hacer `print_r($array3)` obtendrás el siguiente resultado:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [ID] => 2
            [TokenPersona] => 54N65J4K7B6H9B76N9L67KJ54J5VN3B
            [Contenido] => POP DAT!
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [ID] => 5
            [TokenPersona] => 54N65J4
            [Contenido] => DAT POP!
        )
)
```

Comment: Suena muy bien, déjame intentarlo :)

Comment: @MáximaAlekz Lo he modificado con `print_r` para que la respuesta se parezca mucho más a la tuya.

Comment: Bien hecho, aunque pensé que esa clase de unión se hacía con **array_merge**, muchas gracias.

Comment: @MáximaAlekz `array_merge` solo te combinará ambos arrays si son numéricos pero la combinación la hará sobreescribiendo  los valores si son asociativos. Por eso te sugerí al principio el otro método. Sin embargo, creo que esta es la manera más sencilla de combinar los arrays tal y como querías. Un saludo y me alegro de haberte ayudado ^^

Answer (score 2):

**Sí** puedes usar la función `array_merge()` solo hay que empaquetar cada `array` en un `array`:

```
array_merge( [ $array1 ], [ $array2 ] ) );
```

Podemos crear una simple función `array_merge_new()`:

```
function array_merge_new($arr1, $arr2) {

    return array_merge([$arr1], [$arr2]);
}

print_r(array_merge_new($array1, $array2));
```

[Ver Demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/f06ef2abbeccef4e9bbb556476f900d2c4033e13)

Comment: Wow, eso fue muy ingenioso :) 

Aunque no sabría cual de las respuestas es **más** eficiente. :(