# Foreach con dos array

Tags: php, mysql

Tengo dos array que salen de dos select multiple que quiero combinar para almacenarlos en mysql

estoy utilizando un foreach para recorrer uno de ellos pero quisiera saber si existe la opción de recorrer los dos y almacenarlos, hasta ahora este el es codigo que uso.

```
foreach($_POST["dato"] as $Dato) { 
    foreach($_POST["dato2"] as $Dato2) { 
    $INuevo = Insertar_Datos("Codigos" ,"`que`,`idcosa`,`1`,`2`" , "'test','$Id_Numero','".$Dato."','".$Dato2."' ");
}
}
```

el caso es que quiero hacer el bucle que primero lea un dato del primer array y entonces recorra el segundo insertando datos del segundo con un valor del primero ( con esto en principio no tengo problema una vez sepa cual serian las variables que tengo que pasarle al query).
por ejemplo supongamos que son nombres y apellidos los datos:

nombre = 1

apellido = 1 del nombre 1

apellido = 2 del nombre 1

apellido = 3 del nombre 1

nombre = 2

apellido = 1 del nombre 2

apellido = 2 del nombre 2

apellido = 3 del nombre 2

y así hasta el fin de los días pudiendo tener solo dos apellidos o uno solo.

¿se puede o tengo que hacer otro foreach dentro del foreach? ¿quizás sea mejor un for dentro del primer foreach?

dentro de la función Insertar_Datos tengo esto:

```
function Insertar_Datos() { global $Conectar;
    $Parametros = func_get_args();
            $InDatos = "INSERT INTO `".$Parametros[0]."` (".$Parametros[1].") VALUES (".$Parametros[2].");";
            $RDatos = mysqli_query($Conectar, $InDatos);
            if (!$RDatos) { http_response_code(500); print(mysqli_error($Conectar)); } else { http_response_code(200); echo "ok"; }
     return $RDatos;
}
```

y los select multiples son algo así:

```
<select name="dato[]" multiple="multiple">
    <option value="1">Numero 1</option>
    <option value="2">Numero 2</option>
    <option value="3">Numero 3</option>
</select>

<select name="dato2[]" multiple="multiple">
    <option value="1">Numero 1</option>
    <option value="2">Numero 2</option>
    <option value="3">Numero 3</option>
</select>
```

La estructura de la tabla seria algo tipo esto:

```
+----------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field    | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+----------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| id       | int(10)     | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| que      | varchar(50) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| idcosa   | int(10)     | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| 1        | varchar(200)| YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| 2        | varchar(200)| YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+----------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

idcosa me lo traigo de otra tabla y es un numero para identificar de donde viene, pero ese numero lo guarda bien.

El caso es que por alguna razón en cuanto dato2 tiene mas de un valor no funciona y no se que tengo mal :_(

Comment: ¿Puedes mostrar algo más de código? ¿Qué tienes en el método Insertar_Datos?

Comment: Añadido mas datos :)

Comment: ¿A ver si lo entiendo bien, ¿lo que quieres es combinar ambos array para después insertarlos?

Comment: Si exactamente eso. Bueno comprobando que no existan ya

Comment: Posible duplicado de [PHP - Combinación de Array](http://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/36274/php-combinaci%c3%b3n-de-array)

Comment: Creo que no es exactamente combinarlos así, mas bien seria algo tipo esto:  foreach($_POST["dato"] as $Dato) { 
 foreach($_POST["dato2"] as $Dato2) { 
 $INuevo = Insertar_Datos("Codigos" , "`que`,`idcosa`,`1`,`2`" , "'test','$Id_Nuevo','".$Ddato."','".$Ddato2."' ");
}
}

Comment: Lo que estas haciendo se llama [`producto cartesiano`](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Producto_cartesiano), en tu caso de 2 arreglos y como lo has resuelto es la forma correcta. No veo la razón para complicar más el código. ¿O acaso tienes algún error?

Comment: De momento que no funciona XD si el array 2 tiene mas de 1 valor no guarda nada

Comment: ¿Podrías [editar](http://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/41403/edit) tu pregutna y agregar la estructura de la tabla? Para mi que el problema esta en la DB. **PD**: Para responder a alguien usa `@[nombre_del_usuario]` de lo contrario nadie que comente se entera de tu respuestas, a no se que entre nuevamente a ver la pregunta.

Comment: Hola @MarcosGallardo no sabia que había que mencionar como en twitter XD que soy nuevo aquí... ya he puesto la estructura

Comment: ¿La columna `id` es `autoincrement`? Si no lo es, ese puede ser el error que estamos buscando. Por otro lado, ¿es obligatorio que el usuario seleccione al menos un valor en ambos arreglos? si la respuesta es no, deberías replantear como estas haciendo el guardado de tus datos.

Comment: @MarcosGallardo si es autoincrement, no es obligatorio.. y que otra forma puedo usar para guardarlo?

Comment: Te recomendaría [editar](http://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/41403/edit) tu pregunta, cambiar el titulo y mencionar que quieres obtener es el _"producto cartesiano"_ de 2 arreglos. También agregar en la descripción que ambos arreglos pueden estar vacíos (no es obligatorio seleccionar alguna opción) y en la estructura de la tabla indicar que `id` es `autoincrement`. Vas a ver que después de hacerlo vas a recibir mas y mejores respuestas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para calcular el [`producto cartesiano`](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Producto_cartesiano) de ambos arreglos podrías usar la siguiente función:

```
function cartesianProduct($sets)
{
    $cartesian = array();
    foreach ($sets as $key => $set) {

        // Si un grupo esta vació no afecta el producto cartesiano
        if (empty($set)) {
            continue;
        }

        // Si esta vacio agregamos el primer grupo
        if (empty($cartesian)) {
            $cartesian[] = array();
        }

        $subset = array();
        foreach ($cartesian as $product) {
            foreach($set as $value) {
                $product[$key] = $value;
                $subset[] = $product;
            }
        }
        $cartesian = $subset;
    }
    return $cartesian;
}
```

[Demo](http://rextester.com/UYPXIK41716)

Tu código podría resultar en lo siguiente:

```
$set = cartesianProduct(array('dato'=> $_POST['dato'], 'dato2'=> $_POST['dato2']));

foreach($set as $data) {
    $INuevo = Insertar_Datos("Codigos" ,"`que`,`idcosa`,`1`,`2`" , "'test','$Id_Numero','".$data['dato']."','".$data['dato2']."' ");
}
```

Comment: Te quiero. No entiendo el código pero funciona, así que te quiero <3

Answer (score 0):

A lo que logro entender tienes: `$_POST['datos']` y `$_POST['datos2']` y quieres combinarlos para recorrerlos. Pues podrías combinarlos con `array_merge()`: http://php.net/manual/es/function.array-merge.php

```
$array = array_merge($_POST['datos'], $_POST['datos2']);
```

Revisa si te funciona de esa forma.

Comment: creo que no....